# z3 - Assert the # of elements with value x == # of elements with value y?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have some string constants in z3, e.g.

```
boxes = [String(x) for x in range(10)]

# Valid values are x or y
for box in boxes:
    s.add(Or([box == val for val in 'xy']))
```

How would I add the constraint that the number of strings that equal "x" == the number of strings that equal "y"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

boxes = [String("s" + str(x)) for x in range(10)]

# Make sure each box is either x or y
for box in boxes:
    s.add(Or(box == StringVal("x"), box == StringVal("y")))

# Count x's and y's
xcount = 0
ycount = 0
for box in boxes:
    xcount += If(box == StringVal("x"), 1, 0)
    ycount += If(box == StringVal("y"), 1, 0)

# Assert the number of x's equal y's
s.add(xcount == ycount)

# Get a model:
if s.check() == sat:
    print (s.model())
else:
    print("No solution")
```

This prints:

```
[s9 = "x",
 s3 = "x",
 s6 = "y",
 s2 = "y",
 s5 = "y",
 s7 = "y",
 s4 = "x",
 s1 = "x",
 s0 = "x",
 s8 = "y"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it matter if I use StringVal("x") vs just "x"?

Comment: In this case the `StringVal` calls are not strictly necessary, i.e., it'll work without them. This is because z3py inserts "coercions" to move back and forth between Python and z3 values. However, I'd strongly recommend against relying on these coercions, and be explicit with them; i.e., use the `StringVal` call. There has been cases in the past where the coercion didn't do what users expected, and it ended up being a bug. (Also, coercions are rather ad-hoc, and not always very consistent. So, avoiding them is a good idea.)